# "Keypress" event is not working correctly, using jQuery & Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a forum in which I change the functionality of tab to enter. When the user presses enter the next input field get focus and somehow iImanage to open the select2 select box on `focusin` event so the select 2 box opens up.

But, when I select the value and press enter in selec2 select box it does not close and remain open on enter key press event but it closes. When I change the enter key event to any keypress event than select2 get close and works fine but I have to do that by enter.

What I want:
When the user selects the value in select2 search-box and presses enter it get close and focus move to next input field or any field.

What i have done so far.

```
$('.search-select').on("focusin",function(event) {
    $('#s2id_form-field-select-3').select2('open');
    event.preventDefault();  
});
```

**Select2 with enter key event which isn't working**

```
$('.select2-input').on("keypress", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $("#select2-drop-mask").click();
                $('#name').focus();
                e.preventDefault();   
                }
       });
```

**Select2 with any keypress event which is working**

```
$('.select2-input').on("keypress", function(event) {
                $("#select2-drop-mask").click();
                $('#name').focus();
                event.preventDefault();         
});
```

**Markup**

```
 <select id="form-field-select-3" name="register_id" class="form-control search-select" required="required">
   <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
   <? $query=$this->dba->get_dropdown('register',array('id','name'));
      foreach($query as $key=>$value):
   ?>
   <option value="<?=$key?>"><?=$value; ?></option>}
  <? endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Apologies in advance for mistakes, this is my first time using Select2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for **keydown**:

```
$('.select2-input').on("keydown", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $("#select2-drop-mask").click();
                $('#name').focus();
                e.preventDefault();   
                }
       });
```

They're a [little different](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html).
In this case, keypress isn't inserting anything into your field.

Comment: done but believe me i have tried round about 10 to 11 ways and i failed thanks alot you made my day

Comment: In my case, what I needed was "keyup" so I could get the current value of .select2-input - keydown gives you the value minus the character the user is typing at that moment.

Answer (score 7):

For me worked

```
$(document).on('keyup keydown', 'input.select2-search__field', function(e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use jQuery to attach a keydown or keypress event handler to capture those events from a Select2;. Therefore, you need to install a keydown event handler that captures the event before Select2 handles it. You can do this with `document.addEventListener('keydown', handler, true);`. That third parameter tells the browser to let your handler handle the keydown event first.

Example:

```
function myhandler(event){
if (event.keyCode == 117) {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

// do what you want when user press F6 on keyboard;
        return false;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', myhandler, true);
```