# Keypress event on select2 textbox is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown.

```
<select class="eselect2" type="text" id="qename" style="width: 390px;"> 

                    <option value="1">NY</option>
          <option value="2">MA</option>
          <option value="3">PA</option>
          <option value="4">CA</option>
                </select>
```

with simple javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $(".eselect2").select2();
    $('.select2-search__field').on("keydown", function(e) {
                    console.log(e.keyCode); // nothing happens
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                }
       });
});
```

I have an event associated with keypress on the input field. It does not get fired since, the textbox is destroyed and recreated each time the dropdown arrow in the select2 is clicked.
I have attached a fiddle for clarity.
http://jsfiddle.net/sizekumar/ckfjzkhj/

Answer (score 1):

Really jQuery keypress event doesn't fire on input.select2-search__field element. But pure js event does. This piece of code works for me

```
document.getElementsByClassName('select2-search__field')[0].onkeypress = function(evt) { console.log(evt); }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This doesn't solve the problem.

I wouldn't call this a duplicate, but I think this answer directly applies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30697173/5948237

```
$('.select2-input').on("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            }
});
```

Comment: It is the code I have used but it does not work. In the new select2 dropdown, there is no element with class select2-input and the input element is destroyed and created dynamically.